# why does C# convertall require 2 parameters

Tags: c#, linq, convertall

I have an array of Car objects

I want to conver them to a list of Vehicle objects

I thought this would work

```
Vehicle[] vehicles = cars.ConvertAll(car=> ConvertToVehicle(car)).ToArray();
```

but its complaining that ConvertAll requires two parameters.

here is the error:

**Error 2   Using the generic method 'System.Array.ConvertAll(TInput[], System.Converter)' requires '2' type arguments  C:\svncheckout\latestTrunk\Utility\test.cs  229 33**

am i using the wrong method here?

Comment: C# does not have a `ConvertAll` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using ConvertAll on an **Array** of cars (Car[]) instead of a **List** of cars (List) which does indeed require two type parameters[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx). If cars is a list your code will work.

Comment: i updated the question to note that i have an ARRAY (not a List).  what is the best practice given that i have an array

Comment: @ooo Array.ConvertAll(cars, c => ConvertToVehicle(car)); ConvertAll is a static method on the Array class.

Answer (score 1):

That's a static function, written before extension methods were introduced, so you can't call it like a method.

Correct syntax:

```
Array.ConvertAll<Vehicle>(cars, car=> ConvertToVehicle(car))
```

Answer (score 1):

While `Array.ConvertAll` pre-dates things like extension methods, your expected behaviour is *exactly* how `Select` works:

```
Vehicle[] vehicles = cars.Select(car=> ConvertToVehicle(car)).ToArray();
```

vs

```
Vehicle[] vehicles = Array.ConvertAll(cars, car=> ConvertToVehicle(car));
```

Differences:

- `Enumerable.Select`, while static, is an extension method - so *appears* to be an instance method
- `Array.ConvertAll` is static but *isn't* an extension method
- `Enumerable.Select` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, so you need `Enumerable.ToArray` to get an array
- `Array.ConvertAll` returns an array already, and additionally ensures it is the right size much more efficiently than `Enumerable.ToArray` can

Answer (score 0):

If Car is a Sub Type of Vehicle Super Type you can do the following.It should work equally well if ConvertToVehicle returns a Vehicle type.

```
class Vehicle { }
class Car : Vehicle { }

class Program
{
    static List<Car> ll = new List<Car>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Vehicle[] v = ll.ConvertAll<Vehicle>(x => (Vehicle)x).ToArray();
    }
}
```